# Some method is not resolvable

Tags: php, composer-php, slim

Work on API project. Everything good until I have to add a new endpoint (new method too) and I got this Error for my new endpoint, another endpoint run well. Below is error log:

```
Type: RuntimeException
Message: [{“container”:{}},“getNotification”] is not resolvable
File: /opt/myanime/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolver.php
Line: 104
Trace

#0 /opt/myanime/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolver.php(62): Slim\CallableResolver->assertCallable(Array)
#1 /opt/myanime/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolverAwareTrait.php(45): Slim\CallableResolver->resolve(‘UserController:…’)
#2 /opt/myanime/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(333): Slim\Routable->resolveCallable(‘UserController:…’)
#3 /opt/myanime/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(122): Slim\Route->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#4 /opt/myanime/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(316): Slim\Route->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#5 /opt/myanime/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(476): Slim\Route->run(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#6 /opt/myanime/api/src/MyanimeMiddleware.php(121): Slim\App->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#7 [internal function]: App\MyanimeMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Object(Slim\App))
#8 /opt/myanime/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/DeferredCallable.php(43): call_user_func_array(Object(App\VestiaMiddleware), Array)
#9 [internal function]: Slim\DeferredCallable->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Object(Slim\App))
#10 /opt/myanime/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(73): call_user_func(Object(Slim\DeferredCallable), Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Object(Slim\App))
#11 /opt/myanime/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(122): Slim\App->Slim{closure}(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#12 /opt/myanime/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(370): Slim\App->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#13 /opt/myanime/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(295): Slim\App->process(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#14 /opt/myanime/api/public/index.php(35): Slim\App->run()
#15 {main}
```

My routes for new endpoint:

```
$app->get('/user/notification', 'UserController:getNotification');
```

My class:

```
class UserController{
    public function __construct($container)
    {
        // make the container available in the class
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function getNotification($request, $response, $args){
        //my code here
    }
}
```

my `dependencies.php`:

```
use App\Controllers\UserController;
$container = $app->getContainer();
$container['UserController'] = function ($c) {
    return new UserController($c);
};
```

my `composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "slim/slim-skeleton",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
           "App\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

tried to `composer dump-autoload` but that did not work.

Comment: what is the `namespace` of `UserController`? perhaps you will need to specify it in `$app->get('/user/notification', 'UserController:getNotification');`.

Comment: Hi @BagusTesa, Ithe namespace is `namespace App\Controllers;
`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP cannot find your class.

1. require it in the index.php
2. Fix your PSR-0/4 autoload schema and then dump-autoload

Comment: Hi Script, already do it with setting required `require __DIR__ . '/../src/dependencies.php';` on `/public/index.php`. And in my `dependencies.php` I inject my controller like 
    use App\Controllers\UserController;
    $container = $app->getContainer();
    $container['UserController'] = function ($c) {
  return new UserController($c);
    };

Comment: You don't need the last assignment bit and you still have not satisfied my two points above.

Comment: did the 1st point and then dump autoload but still got the same error. 

any reference for the 2nd point? I don't get it, there is no update on my `composer.json` and there is no problem in the other case on another API/method with same class (UserController)

Comment: Apparently you are not using PSR-autoload so disregard the second point. However, your require is still not resolving, put a bootstrap.php file on the root of the project and set a define ('APP_ROOT', __DIR_); use that to resolve your files.

Comment: I already call `require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';` on my `public/index.php`
`

Comment: autoload.php is not loading UserController. So do it manually.

Comment: Hi Script, thanks. I checked it and it is loading. I have API [GET] `/user/profile` using a method in the `UserController` and it works, that is why I think `autoload.php` is loading well.

Answer (score 0):

Not carefully when `rsync` to the server. I uploaded to wrong dir `Controller` instead `Controllers`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I get there. In my case, Slim couldn't instanciate the Controller class because it was simply misspelled.

Answer (score -1):

`'UserController:getNotification'` is not a valid callable based on the code provided. Use either a static function `'UserController::getNotification'` or construct UserController and pass `array($controller, "getNotification")` to `$app->get()`.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the help. I tried to change the method and call it as static function and got message `Callable UserController::getNotification does not exist`. Tried to construct the controller and got the same error with the message `[{“container”:{}},“getNotification”] is not resolvable`