# Navigating to different webpages on a website through routing

Tags: php, html, angular2-routing, slim

I have a webpage which from which i want to navigate to other webpages from the navigation, currently i can only get one web page working, i tried to copy the code for a different web page but it didnt work.

Below is my route.php file currently option 1 works fine but option 2 does not.

```
<?php

use App\Middleware\AuthMiddleware;
use App\Middleware\GuestMiddleware;

$app->get("/", "HomeController:index")->setName("home");
$app->get("/option1", "HomeController:option1")->setName("option1");

$app->get("/option2", "HomeController:option2")->setName("option2");
```

Furthermore, below is my .php file code for the navigation bar.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
  </button>
  <a href=<?php echo $router->pathFor("home");?> class="navbar-brand"> 
<img src=<?php echo $_SESSION['baseUrl'] . "css/images/wwa4f.png";?> 
alt="WWA4F Logo"></a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">


  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="<?=$router->pathFor('option1')?>" >Cuisines</a></li>
  </ul>

         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="<?=$router->pathFor('option2')?>" >Location</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Option 1 which is my cuisines page is working fine as it is allowing me to navigate to it but option 2 which is location page is not but the name location is coming up on navigation bar and when i click location i am getting the error of:

SLIM APPLICATION ERROR

> message: [{"container":{}},"option2"] is not resolvable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46686371/solved-slim-framework-some-method-is-not-resolvable named as solved but without a marked answer.

Comment: Anychance you could help me with this please, im not very experienced on programming and this is a bit new to me. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, PHP (or SLIM) is not my thing, but this error is likely to be caused by the 'option2' class not being found, or not routed properly. Take a look at the other question mentioned above and check that you have done all of the same configuration for 'option2' as the OP did with 'getNotification'. If you have, look at the suggestions/answers given. Failing that, you could add a comment to the OP's question asking what 'SOLVED' it for them.